# why spring-boot can't connect to local mysql server(Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES))

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I encountered a very strange phenomenon about Spring boot and use mysql to store data, today in my private computer I git cloned my developing project. When run the entry main class in eclipse, it throws exception

```
2015-11-15 18:28:08.912 ERROR 9183 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar:5.1.36]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar:5.1.36]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar:5.1.36]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar:5.1.36]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1665) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar:5.1.36]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1207) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar:5.1.36]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2249) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar:5.1.36]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2280) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar:5.1.36]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2079) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar:5.1.36]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar:5.1.36]
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar:5.1.36]
```

it's application.properties :

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foo?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8

spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 123456
```

but I could login mysql directly in terminal, see below:

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -p123456
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 50
Server version: 5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)
```

and I even write a sample java code in the same project to test connection with local mysql server,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foo?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "123456";
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url , user  , password);
    System.out.println(connection);
    Statement stat = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select version()");
    rs.next();
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

Run it have normal output:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@48cf768c
5.6.27-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
```

So why spring-boot can't connect to local mysql server, but other ways could?

Comment: Looks allright - did you check the classic - trailing space in the password?

Comment: Thanks!  You are right indeed there is a space at tail.

Comment: BTW, do you know some better method to output password in main Application Class. Now my way is:@Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
  private String password; and in addInterceptors() add this statement: System.out.println("password: "+password);
    System.out.println("password == 123456: "+("123456".equals(password)));

Comment: @MathiasDpunkt that's it! Only in my case it was trailing space after the user name. D'oh!

Comment: did you find a solution?